# Criteria of normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ be a vector consisting of i.i.d. random variables $X_1,…,X_n$, where $n \geq 2$. Then $X$ is normally distributed if and only if for every orthogonal matrix $A$ of order n, $AX$ and $X$ share the same distribution.
I come across difficulty when dealing with this question. I tried my best to calculate its characteristic function. But I ended up with a terrible functional equation, such as,
$f(r\cos(\theta)) + f(r\sin(\theta))$ doesn’t rely on $\theta$.(When $n = 2$, you can easily get it.) But I can’t go ahead anymore.

Comment: You've clearly put in some work trying to solve this, but it might be a good Idea if you wrote out exactly what you have tried. This could help users help you to determine if you were on the right track, or if you need a completely new approach

Comment: Thanks for everyone. I solved the equation just now.

Comment: hi @user884626, can you post your solution here as well for others that might come later?